# Manage Schedules In JasperReports Server 4.5

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am wondering if anyone has come up with a good method for managing scheduled reports in *JasperReports Server*. We have a multi tenant environment and there can be hundreds of users with the ability to schedule reports. I want the ability to view ALL reports currently scheduled, who submitted them, when they last ran, are scheduled to run next, and if possible if they are currently active (running). I know that *JR Server* doesn't currently offer anything via it's UI for doing this so not sure what options if any may be available to aid with this type of visibility. If anyone has come up with a good method for accomplishing this I'd love to hear how you were able to accomplish.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: JasperReports Server 4.7 has many new APIs to handle schedule management (but no improvements to the core scheduling UI). For example you can get all schedules or search on schedules by any criteria. It doesn't answer your question about 4.5... but it's an important side note.

Comment: Good to know........any ideas when 4.7 is expected to be released?

Comment: this is still a problem My I am looking at the QRTZ tables as a way to get at this information